# Font Sizing Issue for Responsive Navigation Menu

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, font-size, responsive

I created a responsive navigation menu, but some of the headings are longer words, so they become scrunched up or overlap when the screen size shrinks. Is there an easy way to make my font size responsive without having to make several media queries per font break-point? Thanks!

Codepen: https://codepen.io/caguilera0001/pen/VKkQxy

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">

<title>Test Nav Bar</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon (1).ico" type="image/x-icon"/>

<style>

a {
text-decoration: none;
}


ul, li {

    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    box-sizing:border-box;  /** add this **/
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /** add this **/
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /** add this **/
 -ms-box-sizing:border-box; /** add this **/
   background-color: #4484CE;
}

#nav > a {
    display: none;
}


#nav li {
    position: relative;
}

#nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}

#nav span:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 0.313em solid transparent; /* 5 */
    border-bottom: none;
    content: '';
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: -0.313em; /* 5 */
}

/* first level */

#nav > ul {
    height: 30px;
    background:#93C178;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#nav > ul > li {
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
}

#nav > ul > li > a {
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block ;
    color: #FFF; 
    border: 1px solid #4484CE;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; 
    font-size: 14px;
}

#nav > ul > li:hover > a, #nav > ul:not( :hover ) > li.active > a {
    background-color: #F9CF00;
}

/* second level */

#nav li ul {
    background:#93C178;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

}

#nav li:not( :first-child ):hover ul {
    left: -1px;
}

#nav li ul a {
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #4484CE;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; 
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#nav li ul li a:hover, #nav li ul:not( :hover ) li.active a {
    background:#FCFCFC;
    color: #465C8B;
}


 @media only screen and ( max-width: 62.5em ) /* 1000 */ {

#nav {
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
    margin: 0;
}

}

 @media only screen and ( max-width: 40em ) /* 640 */ {

html {
    font-size: 75%; /* 12 */
}

#nav {
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    background-color: none;
}

#nav > a {
    width: 3.125em; /* 50 */
    height: 3.125em; /* 50 */
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-color: #e15a1f;
    position: relative;
}

#nav > a:before, #nav > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    top: 35%;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    content: '';
}

#nav > a:after {
    top: 60%;
}

#nav:not( :target ) > a:first-of-type, #nav:target > a:last-of-type {
    display: block;
}

/* first level */

#nav > ul {
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#nav:target > ul {
    display: block;

}

#nav > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}

#nav > ul > li > a {
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 0.833em; /* 20 (24) */
}

#nav > ul > li:not( :last-child ) > a {
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4484CE;
}

/* second level */

#nav li ul {
    position: static;
    padding: 1.25em; /* 20 */
    padding-top: 0;
}
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<nav id="nav" role="navigation">
    <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation"><img src="hamburger button.png" width="48" height="48" alt="menu button" longdesc="hamburger button.png" /></a>
    <a href="#" title="Hide navigation"><img src="hamburger button.png" width="48" height="48" alt="menu button" longdesc="hamburger button.png" /></a>
<ul>

<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

<li>
<a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">About Us</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="principal's_message.html">Principal's Message</a></li>
    <li><a href="mission_and_vision.html">Mission and Vision</a></li>
    <li><a href="our_history.html">Our History</a></li>
    <li><a href="staff_directory.html">Staff Directory</a></li>
    <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
    <li><a href="photo_gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">School Offices</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="attendance_office.html">Attendance</a></li>
    <li><a href="counseling_office.html">Counseling</a></li>
    <li><a href="main_office.html">Main</a></li>
    <li><a href="magnet_office.html">Magnet</a></li>
    <li><a href="bridge_office.html">Bridge</a></li>
    <li><a href="english_learner's_office.html">EL</a></li>
    <li><a href="itd_office.html">ITD</a></li>
    <li><a href="library.html">Library</a></li>
    <li><a href="parent_center.html">Parent Center</a></li>
    <li><a href="nurse's_office.html">Nurse</a></li>
    <li><a href="safety_ofifice.html">Safety</a></li>
    <li><a href="plant_manager's_office.html">Plant Manager</a></li>
    <li><a href="cafeteria.html">Cafeteria</a></li>
    <li><a href="student_store.html">Student Store</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">Academics</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="classes_homework.html">Classes/Homework</a></li>
    <li><a href="culmination_requirements.html">Culmination</a></li>
    <li><a href="departments.html">Departments</a></li>
    <li><a href="counseling_office.html">Counseling</a></li>
    <li><a href="library.html">Library</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">Programs</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.bancroftib.weebly.com" target="new">IB</a></li>
    <li><a href="middle_years_programme.html">The Middle Years</a></li>
    <li><a href="ste[+a]m_program.html">STEA[+a]M</a></li>
    <li><a href="vei-jv.html">VEI-JV</a></li>
    <li><a href="gate_sas_program.html">GATE/SAS</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://lacerstars.org/" target="new">LACER</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">Students</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href= "cougar_news.html">Cougar News</a></li>
    <li><a href= "bell_schedule.html">Bell Schedule</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "classes_homework.html">Classes/Homework</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "dress_code.html">Dress Code</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "cougar_code.html">Cougar Code</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "attendance_policy.html">Attendance Policy</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "culmination_requirements.html">Culmination</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "http://www.bancroftib.weebly.com/learner-profile.html" target="new">IB Learner Profile</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "http://achieve.lausd.net/cms/lib08/CA01000043/Centricity/Domain/317/24359_OSO_PrntStdntHndbk1516_eng.pdf" target="new">Student Handbook</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "library.html">Library</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "map.html">Map</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "http://achieve.lausd.net/site/default.aspx?PageType=3&ModuleInstanceID=1555&ViewID=7B97F7ED-8E5E-4120-848F-A8B4987D588F&RenderLoc=0&FlexDataID=16590&PageID=845" target="new">Food Menu</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "student_store.html">Student Store</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "http://www.bancroftmiddleschool.org/2015-16yearbook/index.html" target="new">Yearbook</a></li> 
</ul>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">Parents</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href= "parent_bulletin.html">Parent Bulletin</a></li>
    <li><a href= "cougar_news.html">Cougar News</a></li>
    <li><a href= "parent_center.html">Parent Center</a></li>
    <li><a href= "calendar.html">Calendar</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "bell_schedule.html">Bell Schedule</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "classes_homework.html">Classes/Homework</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "culmination_requirements.html">Culmination</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "http://achieve.lausd.net/cms/lib08/CA01000043/Centricity/Domain/317/24359_OSO_PrntStdntHndbk1516_eng.pdf" target="new">District Handbook</a></li>
    <li><a href= "school_site_council.html">SSC Council</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "school_decision_making_council.html">SDM Council</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "elac.html">ELAC</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "contact_teachers.html">Contact Teachers</a></li> 
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>

</ul>
</li>

</ul>
</nav>

<script src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="doubletaptogo.js"></script>
<script>
    $( function()
    {
        $( '#nav li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo();
    });
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Much better if can provide a fiddle for us.

Comment: Absolutely. You can choose between those online code editors.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. Here: https://codepen.io/caguilera0001/pen/VKkQxy

Comment: When the media query for the 640 pixels and below is in action, the subheadings overlap. Any way I can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add media queries.

For Example depending on what screen size you want.

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #nav {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Would I have to add them for every breakpoint the font goes out of place/ scrunches up?

Comment: If I were you I'd slowly shrink the screen and put breakpoints where the font is breaking up, that way your text will be perfect. :)

Comment: That was my original plan, I just wanted to see other ideas. I just might do that though, thank you so much!

Comment: When the media query for the 640 pixels and below is in action, the subheadings overlap. Any way I can fix that?

Comment: I think you really need to go back to the basics of responsive design and learn how everything works and you should have a better idea, I can't see your project so I cant really comment on how to fix it. A codepen that works would be great, your other one wasn't working..

Comment: https://codepen.io/caguilera0001/pen/VKkQxy here, it should work now. I really appreciate this, thank you so much!

Comment: hey, I think this change caused the flexslider below my navbar not to show. Can you please help with that?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403948/responsive-navbar-hides-flexsldier OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382992/responsive-nav-bar-hides-element-below-it

Answer (score 1):

I can see you don't have Bootstrap linked in the site, so I'd recommend if you are making responsive stuff to use it because it makes resizing so much easier.

Check out this: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ 
If you open the page and resize the window the "Getting Started" heading will shrink as it gets smaller, which is what you're looking for.

So just grab the framework off the above site and it will allow your site to function better, responsive wise. Bootstrap does the hard work for you!

Comment: Ok, I half understand what you are saying. So I download Bootstrap and then what? Do I have to link it to my page? How do I implement the download then?

Comment: After you download it, put the CSS and JS files that come with it in your project and link the bootstrap CSS and JS in your HTML. Once its linked youll then be able to let it function in the website. It can be a little confusing , so have a read through the Getting Started section of the website from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template and also http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that

Comment: No worries, a lot of websites run on the Bootstrap framework these days, so if you haven't used it before then it's a really handy tool to learn

Answer (score 1):

@Citlalipop Personally I would make your snap point for your mobile menu at 925px instead of 640 because you're still going to have the problem with "School Offices" going 2 lines.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that too. I'll send an updated codepen soon