# Responsive Nav Bar Hides Element Below it

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive, responsive-nav

I created a responsive navigation bar, but it makes the element below, a Flexslider plug-in, disappear. Before I made the navigation bar, the Flexslider below would show up just fine, but now it doesn't. The z-index for the navbar is at 2, so I don't know what the problem is. How/What should I change to allow the Flexslider to show and the Navigation bar to still be responsive? Thank you!

My code is a bit lengthy, so there are code pens in the comments (it won't let me post them up here for some reason)

Here is a link to the website without the responsive navigation, but it shows the Flexslider: http://bancroftmiddleschool.org

Link to file with Responsive Navigation, but doesn't show Flexslider: http://bancroftmiddleschool.org/index%20copy.html

Comment: Code Pen with responsive navigation, but hides flexslider:http://codepen.io/caguilera0001/pen/JRdpGV                                     (note Flexslider does not appear in codepen for some reason)

Comment: Anyone let me know why this question was downgraded so I can elaborate or fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Change the position CSS in #navBar from position:absolute; to position: relative;.

```
#navBar{
    position: relative;
    /* leave rest of the css unchanged */
}
```

Hope that's the desired effect.

Comment: I tried it, but the flexslider still wouldn't show up

Comment: Is the second link you added the desired effect?

Comment: Yes, the second link in the post. it should be uploaded by now. If not, it may need more time to upload.

Comment: even if it is not uploaded, the flex slider won't show when I test the page on the testing server anyway. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: get a solution yet?

Comment: Didn't get the solution yet.. But I noticed that when I am hovering over the img src in the browser DOM..Img size is coming as 0px*0px. Can you check that out. Try to give some inline height and width and check once. I checked in chrome.

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution. Do you know how I can fix that?